# Create function in Python

Tags: python, function

I have a school project and they asked for grade program using de[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOjTv.jpg)f function for this
A+ 90
A 86
A- 82
B+ 78
.......
I tried to do it without the def function cause I don't know how should I use def function can anyone help me

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: The chapter "[Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)" in the tutorial might help. An make sure that every value a functions needs is given to it with parameters and that you give back value(s) with `return`.

Comment: it should be self study it's not allowed to ask for their help

Comment: You really want to replace all those `else`-`if` cascades with `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this tutorial of how use functions in python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

This is the basic usage of a function.

def my_function():
print("Hello from a function")

my_function()

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_name(x):
    if x =< 50 :
       return "F"

print(function_name(42))
```

This simple example I guess the same thing you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think [RealPython](https://realpython.com/) is an incredible source of Python knowledge.

[Here](https://realpython.com/defining-your-own-python-function/) you can find a very useful tutorial on how to create functions in Python:

```py
def <function_name>([<parameters>]):
    <statement(s)>
```